# Should I use asort after array_unique if the array was asorted before?

Tags: php, arrays, function, array-unique, asort

```
$arr = asort($arr);

//some magic code goes here, $arr is not changed

$arr = array_unique($arr);
```

Should I use asort again to be sure `$arr` is asorted?
My tests show that no, I don't. But I'm not sure for 100% if `array_unique` actually removes the 2nd+ repeated elements.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php Remove the duplicated values.. :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You merely want to ensure that `asort` and `array_unique` use the same sort_flags.

By default:

- array array_unique ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING ] )
- bool asort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )

So you can see that each will sort based on a different algorithm, which might mostly match up, but you want it to explicitly match up. Thus, the smart money is on making a decision like:

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
asort($input,SORT_REGULAR);
print_r($input);
print "\n";
$result = array_unique($input,SORT_REGULAR);
print_r($result);
```

Resulting in:

```
 Array
(
    [1] => blue
    [a] => green
    [b] => green
    [2] => red
    [0] => red
)

Array
(
    [1] => blue
    [a] => green
    [2] => red
)
```

Also note that if you merely run `array_unique` without the initial `asort`, you will get different results.

Finally note that `asort` supports two flags that `array_unique` does not support:

1. `SORT_NATURAL` - compare items as strings using "natural ordering"
   like    natsort()
2. `SORT_FLAG_CASE` - can be combined (bitwise OR) with
   `SORT_STRING` or `SORT_NATURA`L to sort strings case-insensitively

If you use either of these two in your `asort` then you would necessarily need to `asort` again after `array_unique`.

Answer (score 2):

No you do not need to. array_unique will only remove elements, so the order will always be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not modify the array after the 'asort()', the array will be ordered.

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't. The function `array_unique` preserves keys, so there is no need to sort it again.